# I Want animation between activities like skout app

Tags: android, android-activity, android-animation

I am creating an app that have left right gesture. if i swipe screen left side open a new half screen and if i swipe right same scenario.
 this happens all the time whatever screen shows to user .
 like skout app does 
 thanks in advance .

Answer (score 1):

I think that what you want to implement is a sliding menu.
Since it is a new design pattern there is not an official class to generate it yet (but since Google is also pushing this design pattern, for example with its own Google+ app, they will probably add it in a future version of the SDK). 
There are libraries that handle it though :-). [Like this one for example.](https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu)

Comment: Hello Teovald ,i tried this code but not working.Have you any other idea ?

Comment: Hello Teovald ,i tried this code but not working.Have you any other idea ?

Comment: If you followed the instructions in the project and it does not work, you have two options :
-figuring out yourself what does not work and fork the project with your fix (and eventually open a pull request so that everyone can use the fix)
- open a ticket in the github of the project and explain your issue to the project creator.

Without more infos; I can not really help you. Don't expect this library to give you a way to drag & click  & voilà, your work is done.. You have some coding to do.

Comment: I checked the project's repo. It contains a sample project. Getting it up and running should be your first step.